# Change paragraph font in scrjura

Tags: fonts, koma-script

I tried to change the font of each title from sans to the default font type of the normal text using `\addtokomafont`. It works for the main title but it doesn't seem to work for the paragraphs. Any ideas?

The following code

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[juratotoc]{scrjura} 
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\addchap{Contract Title}
\begin{contract}
\Paragraph{title={Paragraph Title}}
Some text
\end{contract}
\end{document}
```

gives me this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In class `scrjura` the Paragraph titles are handled by the new command `\Clause`.  Please see that in an older version of `scrjura` the command `\Paragraph` was used.  Change that to `\Clause` (see warning in `.log` file!)

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[juratotoc]{scrjura} 

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{contract.Clause}{\rmfamily} % Font for Clause


\begin{document}
\addchap{Contract Title}
\begin{contract}
\Clause{title={Paragraph Title}} % <========== Paragraph --> clause
Some text
\end{contract}
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result.  With line

```
\addtokomafont{contract.Clause}{\rmfamily} % Font for Clause
```

you can change the font for the titles of Clause ...

That is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an quite old version of scrjura. In newer versions you should use `\Clause` instead of `\Paragraph`. You can change the font then like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[juratotoc]{scrjura}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{contract.Clause}{\rmfamily}
\begin{document}
\addchap{Contract Title}
\begin{contract}
\Clause{title={Paragraph Title}}
Some text
\end{contract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In older versions change the contract.Paragraph font element:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[juratotoc]{scrjura}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{contract.Paragraph}{\rmfamily}
\begin{document}
\addchap{Contract Title}
\begin{contract}
\Paragraph{title={Paragraph Title}}
Some text
\end{contract}
\end{document}
```